# change css display when user scrolls down. Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually i want to create a "Scroll to the top" button without jQuery.
 The go to the top function is already working.
 Now I need to automate the `display: none` to `display: block` when the user scrolls down the page. And the other way when it gets back to the top.

```
<a href="#ancor-top" id="GoTop">Top</a>

#GoTop {
    display: none;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 20px; 
    right: 30px; 
    z-index: 99;
    border: none; 
    outline: none;
    background-color: red; 
    color: white; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    padding: 15px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var goTop = document.getElementById('GoTop');
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  if (this.pageYOffset > 100) {
    goTop.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    goTop.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

```css
div {
  height: 200vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#GoTop {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#ancor-top" id="GoTop">Top</a>
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without using jquery you can acheive this by using Bootstrap section and Scrollspy.

Comment: @KarenBezas did you put the code in a separate file? if so check the path. If its the same path did you put it at the top of the page? then wrap the javascript with the window.onload function or just simply put the code before the end of body tag..

Comment: It was in the beginning of the body tag. I've moved it to the before the end of the body tag, and now it worked ;) thanks!

Comment: @KarenBezas I'm glad I was able to help :)